# Java date concept

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have util dates like `2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23`

I want to  store that dates into mysql database table column date

am using these code

```
String datevalue=request.getParameter("date");
```

this datevalue is printing like this `2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23`.

```
 String[] datetokens=datevalue.split(",");
java.sql.Date dt = java.sql.Date.valueOf(new String(datevalue));
```

In inserting time am getting these error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

give me suggetion howto solve that problem and stored in database

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a date format object to parse the dates such as [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String dateValuesString = request.getParameter("date");
String[] dateValueStrings = dateValuesString.split(",");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
for (String dateString : dateValueStrings) {
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will print each date.

```
String datevalue = "2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23";
        String[] datetokens = datevalue.split(", ");
        for (String each : datetokens) {
            java.sql.Date dt = java.sql.Date.valueOf(each);
            System.out.println(dt);
        }
```

You can insert `dt` to the database. There must be a space after comma (,) in `split` method (like `split(", ")`).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `STR_TO_DATE` function.
Try typeCasting at the time of INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUE (STR_TO_DATE('5/15/2012 8:06:26 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use [JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) to do what you need there; however, SimpleDateFormat or JODA will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is due to wrong format of `datetokens`. It get `blank space`  because of `split(","`). Use `trim()` method

```
for(String token: datetokens){
java.sql.Date dt = java.sql.Date.valueOf(new String(token.trim()));
}
```

Comment: Here am passing datevalue not datetokens

Comment: @kittureddy You right. You should use trim() at datetokens. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this as well:-

```
String dateValuesString = request.getParameter("date");
String[] dateValueStrings = dateValuesString.split(",");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
for (String dateString : dateValueStrings) {
String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(dateString);
 System.out.println(reformattedStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

- You passed a comma (,) seperated list of date values.
  `String datevalue=request.getParameter("date");`
- splited all the dates into an array of strings holding each date value.
  `String[] datetokens = datevalue.split(",");`
  `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", dateValue);`
  ...specify the date format to be parsed.
- now you need to iterate (for loop) to access each of strings in the array.
  `for(String dateValue : datetokens){`
  `Date date = sdf.parse(dateValue.trim());`
  `java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());`
  // here INSERT the `sqlDate` value into MySQL for each iteration.
  `}`
- Please don't forget to manage database connection and provide proper query while inserting.
- Also, handle the `ParseException` ie. either use try/catch or throws.